# Difference in parameter passing to static vs non-static methods

Tags: java

does static methods treat parameters differently than non-static methods? Let say I have following classes/methods in my project:

```
public abstract class A {
   public static void populateList(List<Item> list) {
      list.add(new Item("something")); //Item is custom class
   }
```

And:

```
public class B {
   public void tryToPopulateList(List<Item> list) {
      list.add(new Item("something2"));
   }
```

Now, if I pass my list to class A using `A.populateList(myList)` then pointer to `list` in method body is same as pointer to `myList` in caller and thus this static method actually change `myList` and not only its local copy.

 However if I call:

```
B b = new B();
b.tryToPopulateList(myList);
```

then pointer to `list` in method is different than pointer to `myList` so I guess that local copy for the method is created and "something2" is added to this copy. The result is that original myList is NOT changed in this case.
Is this behavior normal? Do you have any explanation or link to the explenation how passing parameters works in static functions? 
 Yes, I know it would be better to return new List from the function if I want to change the List but I am just currious as I did not find this topic explained anywhere. Thanks.

**EDIT**
As mentioned in comments, parameters are treated the same way in static and non-static methods. I made a mistake in the code not listed here.

Comment: Are you sure that original copy is not modified in 2nd case. I think, it should be modified. Please re-check that.

Comment: There is no difference in parameter treatment in `static` vs. instance methods.

Comment: Well, at least not in my project. I will retest it in the plain Java app but when debugging, I can clearly see that object "list" in method body has different address than "myList" which was passed by caller. Also returner list is unmodified (has zero items...not null). May definition of Item class change anything? It is only String and bool holder.

Comment: there can't different address in method than passed address, please post full code

Comment: You guys are right...my fault. New address for the list in method is created by the line where I assign gson to the list which created the new list instead of changing the current one. Errr...should take a break after hours of development instead of asking stupid questions :(

Comment: @Tom, Please delete the quation asis invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bottom line, All method parameters in Java are values-by-reference.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal circumstances, there should be no difference. All method parameters in Java are passed value-by-reference, meaning that the address (pointer) of the list is copied into parameter of the called method.

I can only think of one situation in which the behavior you describe could occur: Are you using a framework that provides Aspect-Oriented Programming features? It's possible that your non-static method call is being intercepted.

Comment: Well, it is Android project if it makes any difference and only external library in this project is gson.